# Sort data from MongoDB by month and year

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

guys! I have this data inside my MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa35c78e84868839683c4ca"),
    "dateTransacted" : ISODate("2018-03-10T04:18:00.074Z"),
    "taskerFee" : 1500,
    "customerFee" : 4000,
    "transactionFee" : 50,
    "mnmltaskrProfit" : 30
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa3ac08e84868839683c4cb"),
    "dateTransacted" : ISODate("2018-03-10T09:57:28.637Z"),
    "taskerFee" : 300,
    "customerFee" : 1500,
    "transactionFee" : 50,
    "mnmltaskrProfit" : 60
}
```

and I want to query this by month and year so that it would return something like:

```
{
  'month': 'September',
  'year': 2018,
  'transactions': [
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5aa3ac08e84868839683c4cb"),
      "dateTransacted" : ISODate("2018-03-10T09:57:28.637Z"),
      "taskerFee" : 300,
      "customerFee" : 1500,
      "transactionFee" : 50,
      "mnmltaskrProfit" : 60
    },
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5aa3ac08e84868839683c4cb"),
      "dateTransacted" : ISODate("2018-03-10T09:57:28.637Z"),
      "taskerFee" : 300,
      "customerFee" : 1500,
      "transactionFee" : 50,
      "mnmltaskrProfit" : 60
    }
  ]
}
```

what do you suppose i should do?

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!

Comment: Why do you want a query to return a different format of data than in your database ? Your query will most likely return all the transactions in a given range.

Comment: i don't really want to return the same exact format. i just want a way to query the data by month and year.

Comment: So you want to group & sort the entire collection data by month and year  ? Is there a input to your query ?

Comment: basically, yes. the entire collection. no input to my query. just the entire collection of what's inside the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below aggregation.

`$group` by month and year and `$push` with `$$ROOT` to access the whole document followed by `$sort` on month and year desc.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"month":{"$month":"$dateTransacted"},"year":{"$year":"$dateTransacted"}},
    "transactions":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}
  }},
  {"$sort":{"month":-1,"year":-1}}
])
```